# Rendering a viewport to a sprite's texture only gets one quarter of the rendered image. In Godot

Tags: render, viewport, godot

[image]

In the right side I have the Viewport object that renders the OriginalImage.
Then in the left side I have a Sprite whose texture is the output of the Viewport object.

[image]

When running the Scene, I only get one quarter of the image, no matter how I place or offset Viewport, Camera, Sprites, etc.

[image]

For more information, please check the repo and of course pull requests are welcome:
https://github.com/Drean64/godot-viewport

Answer (score 0):

Offset'd the Camera to the center of the viewport, because it was otherwise centered at the viewport's origin.
https://github.com/Drean64/godot-viewport/commit/ccfd095eb4bc23e2c5f385a35921280b878ee3d7